# Global Criterion for Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

For real valued functions of a real variable, is there a global criterion for differentiability?

I feel there should be, as there is a global criterion for continuity - that the inverse of every open set is open. This criterion is global in the sense that it does not refer to any particular point.

Comment: I'm not sure that I see how "the inverse image of every open set is open" is a *global* property.  Indeed, this seems like the very definition of a *local* property (i.e. every point in the codomain is contained in a neighborhood with open preimage). [This question on MSE is relevant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826808/what-is-the-definition-of-local-and-global-properties-and-how-are-they-different)

Comment: I'm looking for a criterion that does not refer to any particular point. If you don't want to call that global, that is fine